# Is there any way to funnel one playback device's audio into another?

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, sound-card

I'm wanting to use my Sound Blaster Z SE's features (like Scout Mode), but funnel the resulting audio into my HyperX headset with surround sound. I know optical out to a headset supporting optical would be the ideal solution (like with some of the Astros headsets), but I can't afford that at this time (though if there's an affordable, passable quality surround sound headset with this functionality, please let me know).

The only other 2 solutions I can think of, if possible, is to either route my Sound Blaster Z speaker or optical playback device into my HyperX device, or have some kind of converter from optical to USB.

Is any of this possible, or is there a better solution? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Third party tools, such as free [JackAudio](https://jackaudio.org/), donation-ware [VB-Cable Virtual Audio Device](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/) or commercial [Virtual Audio Cable](https://vac.muzychenko.net/en/) act as a switchboard, connecting multiple devices and applications.

*Caveat:* As with any software, check it for malware at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) before installing. Also consider that it may take a bit of work to configure the software. For example, it took experimentation to find Jack2 works on my PC by using the *net* driver. Check the [Jack2 Wiki](https://github.com/jackaudio/jackaudio.github.com/wiki) or configuration and other help.

Comment: Appreciate the reply! While I went through the beginner's guide for Jack I got to the Cadence section, but the tool kept saying it couldn't connect to the server no matter what driver I selected and even after telling Windows to allow it network access. Jack may be a bit too advanced for me, but I could simply be missing something. With VB VCables and VM-Potato I can pass stereo sound from my sound card's stereo mix to my headset, but not surround sound since the inputs only allow 2 channels. Dolby Atmos seems to be a good workaround, but not sure if that will work in future use cases.

Comment: Interestingly enough, my card's stereo mix (labeled as "What U Hear") does say it supports 6 channels, but VM-Potato's hardware inputs only seem to allow 2 channels. The virtual inputs do allow surround sound and I can pass that to the card, but then the problem is routing it into the headset from the card.